# why does pyserial write() show me as output the number of characters of the string I want to send?

Tags: python, pyserial

The whole program works except for this, instead of showing me in the console b'N', I get a 1 as output, if I change the N to something longer the output shows me its number of characters. Previously it did show me the correct output, I don't know what I changed :(

```
def readSerial():
data = ser.write(b'N')
print(data)
```

Comment: Shouldn't be a surprise.  Have you read the documentation? https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html. Why would you expect write to return a string of what was written? That would serve no purpose.  Create a string variable and both write and print that.

Answer (score 0):

`serial.write()` returns the number of characters written, not a copy of the string written.

```py
def readSerial():
    data = b'N'
    ser.write(data)
    print(data)
```

Comment: What I wanted to do is not what you mention but thanks to that I found my mistake, I was misreading the information sent to the microcontroller. :D

Comment: @laura I cannot imagine how your question could be interpreted in any other way.  Is the question valid in that case?